# Скролл фиксированных блоков

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

Нужен js скрипт или иное решение, как скролить фиксированный блок вместе с контентной частью, примерно как в vk сделано: http://prnt.sc/dhxzny

Comment: Я уже стыкался с такой "проблемой". Если найду скрипт который писал, то скину

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал новый Jquery скрипт, который более гибкий:

```
$.prototype.sticky = function(status) {
    var e = this,
        elem = {height: $(e).outerHeight(), top: $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top')), bottom: $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top')) + $(e).outerHeight(true), diff: $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('top'))},
      scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(status == true || status == undefined || status == 1 || status == 'on'){
    $(e).prop('sticky', true);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(e).prop('sticky') == true){
            if($(window).height() < $(e).outerHeight(true)){
                if(scrollTop < $(window).scrollTop()){
                elem.bottom = $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top')) + $(e).outerHeight(true);
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > elem.bottom){
                $(e).css({bottom: $(window).scrollTop() * -1, top: 'auto'});
                };
            }else if(scrollTop > $(window).scrollTop()){
                elem.top = $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top'));
                if($(window).scrollTop() < elem.top){
                $(e).css({top: $(window).scrollTop(), bottom: 'auto'});
                };
            };
            scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        }else{
            $(e).css({top: $(window).scrollTop(), bottom: 'auto'});
        };
      };
    });
  }else if(status == false || status == 0 || status == 'off'){
    $(e).prop('sticky', false);
    $(e).css({top: '', bottom: ''});
  };
};
```

Запускается он таким образом:

```
$(elem).sticky(true); // Вместо true можно указать: 1, вообще ничего не указывать, on
```

Так же его можно выключить:

```
$(elem).sticky(false); // Вместо false можно указать: 0 или off
```

Вот живой пример *(пример на внешнем редакторе: [jsfiddle-sj3cd0cL](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/sj3cd0cL/))*:

```js
$.prototype.sticky = function(status) {
 var e = this,
    elem = {height: $(e).outerHeight(), top: $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top')), bottom: $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top')) + $(e).outerHeight(true), diff: $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('top'))},
      scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(status == true || status == undefined || status == 1 || status == 'on'){
   $(e).prop('sticky', true);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(e).prop('sticky') == true){
      if($(window).height() < $(e).outerHeight(true)){
       if(scrollTop < $(window).scrollTop()){
          elem.bottom = $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top')) + $(e).outerHeight(true);
          if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > elem.bottom){
            $(e).css({bottom: $(window).scrollTop() * -1, top: 'auto'});
          };
        }else if(scrollTop > $(window).scrollTop()){
         elem.top = $(e).offset().top - parseFloat($(e).css('margin-top'));
          if($(window).scrollTop() < elem.top){
            $(e).css({top: $(window).scrollTop(), bottom: 'auto'});
          };
        };
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       }else{
        $(e).css({top: $(window).scrollTop(), bottom: 'auto'});
       };
      };
    });
  }else if(status == false || status == 0 || status == 'off'){
   $(e).prop('sticky', false);
    $(e).css({top: '', bottom: ''});
  };
};

$(function() {
 $('.modal').sticky(true);
 $('body').on('click', '#on', function() {
   $('.modal').sticky(true);
    $('#on').attr('id', 'off').html('Отключить sticky');
  });
 $('body').on('click', '#off', function() {
   $('.modal').sticky(false);
    $('#off').attr('id', 'on').html('Включить sticky');
  });
});
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;}
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal">
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;" >
  <button id="off">Отключить sticky</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @АндрейТаланин, лучше не задавайте такие вопросы. Тут не клуб "умелые ручки". Должны быть конкретные вопросы, а не просьбы

Comment: @АндрейТаланин, я написал новый скрипт данному вопросу, смотрите ответ